# Extract private key from .pfx file

Tags: openssl, x509certificate, keytool, pfx

I want to extract private key from .pfx file, for this I am using following Openssl command

```
Openssl pkcs12 -in "filename.pfx" -out "cert.pem" -nodes
```

After running this command; file with name 'cert.pem' is generated, but it is blank file. No content has been found inside it.
I can open that filename.pfx in keyStrore Explorer that means there is nothing wrong with filename.pfx file.
I just want private key from that .pfx file, How can I get this? Is there any way to do the same in KeyStore Explorer or any other way to get private key, Please Help me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: This is part of development only. I need to hit target endpoint which is secure and can only be accessible with Json Web Token(JWT). For that I am creating Java classes. In that I need private Key for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the private and public keys from PFX files. The process is explained here nicely
https://support.sonicwall.com/sonicwall-email-security/kb/sw10754

Comment: broken link... You should always copy the relevant information to mitigate that

Comment: The new version of that link might be [this](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/how-to-extract-a-public-certificate-and-private-key-from-pfx-for-use-in-gms-analyzer-7-2-and-later/170502327527209/)...